# Need to query one collection while referencing and querying another at same time

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have two collections, one for materials and one for materialphotos. I've used a DBref (i think) in order to reference the materialphotos collection. I can't figure out how to write the script so when a user inputs a search query, to then query the material collection and then also query the materialphotos collection to find the appropriate picture. I think the better way would be to redesign the database, but it's not my call. Here's some code so far, and also the DBref...

```
"id": "101",
    "photo": {
        "$ref": "materialphotos",
        "$id": ObjectId("57041fc125e2433c200987ff")
    },

    "material_name": "Something",
```

JS code:

```
var Search = function(materialName) {
     db.collection('materials').find({"material_name": materialName}).toArray(function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
    });
     db.collection('materials').find({'photo.$id': ObjectId("57041fc125e2433c200987ff")});

  }
```

@NeilLunn So, for example, a collection of Products, each with it's own document, would contain a field "Parts" to reference all the parts for that product; and the "Parts" field would contain an array of ObjectID's that reference a parts collection. Did I describe that correctly? Here is some code:

```
> db.products.findOne()
{
    name : 'left-handed smoke shifter',
    manufacturer : 'Acme Corp',
    catalog_number: 1234,
    parts : [     // array of references to Part documents
        ObjectID('AAAA'),    // reference to the #4 grommet above
        ObjectID('F17C'),    // reference to a different Part
        ObjectID('D2AA'),
        // etc
    ]
```

Comment: What exactly are you getting stuck on?

Comment: You Seem to be thinking that the `DBRef` "resolves automatically" somehow to the object in the other collection. It does not. Some "drivers" have a feature to do this, but "most" do not. `DBRef` is an evil and antiquated way of referencing data in another document, wherever it may reside. For many reasons you are better of using a standard `ObjectId` and either another normal property for the referenced collection or an external "schema" declaration with the "target collection" instead.